# How to do syntaxhighlighting for terminal rules in Xtext?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, dsl, xtext

I would like to do custom syntaxhighlighting in xtext. I would like to highlight everything that matches a terminal rule in a specific color.

For example my terminal rule:

```
terminal MYRULE:
    ('ab'|'2')*
;
```

I would like to color the everything like a comment what matches this terminal rule.

I tired the following:

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.eclipse.xtext.ide.editor.syntaxcoloring.HighlightingStyles;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.syntaxcoloring.DefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper;

public class STAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper extends DefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper {

private static final Pattern QUOTED = Pattern.compile("(?:^'([^']*)'$)|(?:^\"([^\"]*)\")$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    
    private static final Pattern PUNCTUATION = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}*");
    
    @Override
    protected String calculateId(String tokenName, int tokenType) {
        
        System.out.println("token = " + tokenName);
        
        
        if ("MYRULE".equals(tokenName)) {
            return HighlightingStyles.COMMENT_ID;
        }
        
        if(QUOTED.matcher(tokenName).matches()) {
            return HighlightingStyles.KEYWORD_ID;
        }
        if("RULE_STRING".equals(tokenName)) {
            return HighlightingStyles.STRING_ID;
        }
        if("RULE_INT".equals(tokenName)) {
            return HighlightingStyles.NUMBER_ID;
        }
        if("RULE_ML_COMMENT".equals(tokenName) || "RULE_SL_COMMENT".equals(tokenName)) {
            return HighlightingStyles.COMMENT_ID;
        }
        
        
        
        return HighlightingStyles.DEFAULT_ID;
    }
```

}

I see the print for "MYRULE". The code is accepted from the editor. But the special code part is not highlighted.

Of course the rule is just an example and not part of the DLS I am working on. But I can't tell details about my DSL.

Comment: i dont understand the quoted stuff. and shouldnt it be RULE_MYRULE instead of MYRULE

Comment: besides that you may look into semantic highlighting

Comment: With the quted code I tried to make a relationship between a rule and a color. For example the default code not written by me says "the single line comment should be highlighted with the style 'comment_id'". 
OK, I missed the naming conventions with MYRULE.

In symantic highlighting they do:
if (node.getGrammarElement() instanceof CrossReference) {
But that does not work for terminal rules. There is no class defined that I can check instanceof with. So my question is, how can I identify teminal rules for highlighting?

Comment: you can have a look at nodes grammar elements and relate that to rules/rulecalls

Comment: If I iterate over the nodes in
INode root = resource.getParseResult().getRootNode();
and print node.getGrammarElement()
I get things like
org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@20a74990.
That is not related to some terminal rule.

Comment: the rulecalls getRule might be a terminal rule

Comment: There is no methon getRule() in the class INode.

Comment: in rulecall is a getRule

Comment: Do you mean node.getGrammerElement().getRule()?
That is also not available.

Comment: > INode root = resource.getParseResult().getRootNode(); and print node.getGrammarElement() I get things like org.eclipse.xtext.impl.RuleCallImpl@20a74990. T
=> cast and getRule on RuleCall ?!?

Comment: cast which object to what?

Comment: if (grammarElement instanceof RuleCall) ((RuleCall)grammarElement).getRule()